# How to check if one can write files into a directory?

Tags: matlab

Tried looking for a function that might be helpful but no luck. My best workaround is to attempt to create a dummy file in a directory using fopen, and if it returns -1 then I know I can't create a file and I don't execute the rest of my code. If I successfully created the file, I'll just delete it and move on with the rest of my code.

This seems like a rather inelegant approach, I would rather just have a line of code that tells me I have no write permission in a given directory. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a  folder:

```
mkdir('folderName')
```

and then use movefile to copy a file into that folder:

```
[status,message,messageid]  = movefile('myfunction.m','oldfunction.m');
```

status is logical 1 for success or logical 0 for error.

You can also get the permissons for a Folder/File like this:

```
fileattrib('C:\my_MATLAB_files\doc')
ans = 

            Name: 'C:\my_MATLAB_files\doc'
         archive: 0
          system: 0
          hidden: 0
       directory: 1
        UserRead: 1
       UserWrite: 1
     UserExecute: 1
       GroupRead: NaN
      GroupWrite: NaN
    GroupExecute: NaN
       OtherRead: NaN
      OtherWrite: NaN
    OtherExecute: NaN
```

So you can do something like this:

```
[S,M] = fileattrib('Directory');
M.UserWrite

ans = 
    1
```